# How to solve the inverse kinematics of a 2DOF system on a rotating platform?

Tags: rotations, angle, orientation, kinematics

I have a 2DOF (z,y axes) stabilization system that needs to maintain the orientation of the end-effector.

Suppose the system is attached to a 3DOF rotating platform and has some fixed joints at the end of the rotation chain. We have no control over the 3DOF platform or the fixed joints, but we can measure the angles. I need to find the joint angles of the 2DOF stabilization system such that the end-effector $x$ vector matches the desired setpoint vector.

In this case, the position does not matter and the system only needs to stabilise the end effector's orientation. The forward kinematics of the end effector can be written as:

$$R_{plat} \underbrace{R_z(\psi) R_y(\theta)}_{\textrm{2DOF system}}R_{fixed} = R_{end} $$
Where $R_{end}$ is the end-effector rotation matrix. $R_{plat}$ is the rotation matrix of the 3DOF (z-y'-x'') platform. $R_{fixed}$ is the fixed z and y joints at the end of the rotation sequence with known angles. $R_z(\psi)$ and $R_y(\theta)$ are the rotations of the 2DOF stabilisation system.

Note that this is what I'm using:
$$ R_{z}(\psi )= \begin{bmatrix} \cos{\psi} & -sin{\psi} & 0 \\ sin{\psi} & cos{\psi} & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$
$$ R_{y}(\theta )= \begin{bmatrix} \cos{\theta}&0&\sin{\theta}\\0&1&0\\-sin{\theta}&0&\cos{\theta}\end{bmatrix}$$
$$ R_{x}(\phi )= \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & \cos{\phi} & -sin{\phi} \\ 0 & \sin{\phi} & cos{\phi} \end{bmatrix}$$

I only need the $x$ vector of the LHS to match the RHS, therefore I need to solve for $\psi$ and $\theta$ such that the equation below holds true.

$$R_{plat} \underbrace{R_z(\psi) R_y(\theta)}_{\textrm{2DOF system}}R_{fixed}\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} = R_{end}\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} $$

**How can I solve for $\psi$ and $\theta$?**

I know this is possible as I am able to get the $x$ vectors to match by brute forcing (see image below for example of what I need to achieve).
[image: Brute force example]

**Here's what I have tried and doesn't work**

I tried rearranging the equation to solve for $R_z(\psi) R_y(\theta)$ like this:
$$R_z(\psi) R_y(\theta) = R_{plat}^{-1} R_{end} R_{fixed}^{-1}$$
However, this does not work as it required three joints to achieve the rotation of the RHS. If I solve for $\psi = \textrm{atan2}(R_{21}, R_{11})$ and $\theta = \sin^{-1}(-R_{31})$, the resulting rotation below is what I got, which is not quite right.
[image]

Thank you so much for taking your time to read and answer!!

Comment: Why don't you compute both sides of your equation and equate them?

Comment: I have tried equating them like this $R_z(\psi) R_y(\theta) = R_{plat}^{-1} R_{end} R_{fixed}^{-1}$, but it doesn't work. The result I got is shown in the graph above with blue lines. You cannot solve for $\psi$ and $\theta$ by arranging it like this apparently. The RHS requires three joints to achieve. It worked if I the system was a 3DOF, ie. $R_z(\psi) R_y(\theta) R_x(\phi)$, however the system is only a 2DOF system.

Comment: You must include vector $[1,0,0]$: your second equation is not the same as the first one, if that vector is present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the following equation:

$ R_{plat} R_z(\psi) R_y (\theta) R_{fixed} e_1 = R_{end} e_1 $

where $e_1 =[1, 0, 0]^T $

Premultiplying both sides by $R_{plat}^T $ , you get

$ R_z(\psi) R_y (\theta) R_{fixed} e_1 = R_{plat}^T R_{end} e_1 $

Let's introduce two vectors $v$ and $w$ as follows

$v = R_{fixed} e_1 $  and $ w = R_{plat}^T R_{end} e_1 $, then

$ R_z(\psi) R_y (\theta) v = w $

Finally, premultiply both sides by $R_z(\psi)^T $, then

$ R_y ( \theta) v = R_z(\psi)^T w \hspace{48pt}(*)$

Note that vectors $v$ and $w$ are unit vectors, but are otherwise arbitrary.  We're now looking for $\theta$ and $\psi$, that will satisfy equation $(*)$.  The left hand side is a rotation of vector $v$ about the $y$ axis while the right hand side is a rotation of $w$ about the $z$ axis.  These two cones will intersect (and thus equation (*) will have a solution) if the acute angles $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ add up to a value that is greater than $90^\circ$, where $\phi_1$ is the acute angle between the $y$ axis and $v$, and $\phi_2$ is the acute angle between   the $z$ axis and $w$.  That is,

$\phi_1 = \cos^{-1} | v_y | $ and $\phi_2 =\cos^{-1} | w_z | $

If $\phi_1 + \phi_2 \gt \dfrac{\pi}{2} $ then we will have two solutions for $\psi$ and $\theta$. (The $\dfrac{\pi}{2}$ comes from the fact that the $y$ and $z$ are pependicular to each other).

Otherwise, no solutions are possible.

Assuming that the condition above is satisfied, then the intersection of the two cones, satisfies the property that,

$ k^T (R_y(\theta) v) = \cos(\phi_2) $

Where $k$ is the unit vector along the $z$ axis.  This equation is a scalar trigonometric equation and can be solved for $\theta$.  There will be two solutions, and for each, the corresponding $\psi$ can be computed from equation $(*)$.

To see how to solve this equation, recall that

$R_y(\theta) = \begin{bmatrix} \cos \theta && 0 && \sin \theta \\ 0 && 1 && 0 \\ -\sin \theta && 0 && \cos \theta \end{bmatrix} $

As a sum of matrices, $R_y(\theta) $ is equal to

$R_y(\theta) = A_0 + A_1 \cos \theta + A_2 \sin \theta $

where

$A_0 = \begin{bmatrix} 0 && 0 && 0 \\ 0 && 1 && 0 \\ 0 && 0 && 0 \end{bmatrix}$

$A_1 = \begin{bmatrix} 1 && 0 && 0 \\ 0 && 0 && 0 \\ 0 && 0 && 1 \end{bmatrix}$

$A_2 = \begin{bmatrix} 0 && 0 && 1 \\ 0 && 0 && 0 \\ -1 && 0 && 0 \end{bmatrix} $

So now our equation becomes:

$ k^T (A_0 + A_1 \cos \theta + A_2 \sin \theta ) v = \cos(\phi_2) $

which simplifies to

$ (k^T A_1 v) \cos \theta + (k^T A_2 v) \sin \theta = \cos(\phi_2) - k^T A_0 v $

Note that $k^T A_0  = [0,0,0] $ and $k^T A_1  = [0, 0, 1] $ and $k^T A_2 = [-1, 0, 0] $

Thus the equation simplifies further to

$v_z \cos \theta - v_x \sin \theta = \cos(\phi_2) = | w_z | $

which is very easy to solve.

Comment: Thanks so much Hosam. I'm getting a weird matrix for $R_y (\theta)$, am I doing something wrong? 
So, here's is what I've got. To solve for $\theta$, I'm rearranging the equation like so:
$$R_y(\theta) = k \phi_2 v^T = [0,0,1]^T \phi_2 [v_x,v_y,v_z]$$
Since $\phi_2$ is scalar, $$R_y(\theta) = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0& 0&0 \\ m_1&m_2&m_3 \end{bmatrix}$$

How do I solve $\theta$ from this?

Comment: I don't know where you got $k \phi_2 v^T $ from.  The equation in my answer is $k^T R_y(\theta) v = \phi_2$

Comment: Sorry, I was just trying to rearrange to solve for $\theta$. I'm not sure how to calculate $\theta$ from the equation $k^T R_y(\theta) v =\phi_2$.

Could you please kindly explain a bit further? You are already a massive help!!!

Comment: @pakornpp Check my updated solution for more details on how to solve the equation $k^T R_y(\theta) v = \cos \phi_2 $

Comment: It worked!! Thank you so much for you help, you're a hero!